# How to use async pipe with RxJS interval on dynamically created component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was wondering if it's somehow possible to use `async` pipe with `RxJS` `interval()` on dynamically created components like in this [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qkjbmvdlygda) . Because if I apply `async` pipe inside of it, then when the components will change the interval will be mostly ignored.

Let's say I want to get data every 15 minutes but the components change every 15 seconds.

The only way I found is to take data from one `Observable` and save it to another one but I don't think that this is the best practice. Is there some other way on how to achieve this or this practice is ok?

The `Observable` looks like this:

```
interval(1000 * 60 * 15).pipe(startWith(0), switchMap(() => this.http.get('someUrl')));
```

Solution I found working:

```
interval(1000 * 60 * 15).pipe(startWith(0), switchMap(() => this.http.get('someUrl'))).subscribe((data) => {
  this.someUrlData = scheduled([data], asapScheduler);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you have looks like it will work and is an acceptable way of doing it. If I were a new developer looking it over, though, I'd probably get confused about it and might attempt an ill-advised re-factor (unless you heavily commented it).

For that reason, I'd try a more readable approach (and forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your use case):

```
getData = new Subject<void>();

// UI Observable (referenced via the async pipe)
someData$ = this.getData.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.http.get('someUrl')),
    shareReplay(1)
)

// Subscriptions (inside ngOnInit)
timer(0, 1000 * 60 * 15).subscribe(() => this.getData.next())
```

The advantage here is you also maintain control over when you get data. You could easily add a "refresh" button to the screen and have it just next on the `getData` subject.

Just be sure to clean up your subscription on the timer, otherwise it will go forever.

---

Update:

To answer your original question, it's 100% best practice to take a value from one Observable and save it to another one. To get around the component being destroyed, though, the best practice is to put this in a service, that way it stays intact.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem here is that the `async` pipe will gone when the component is destroyed. So the request will be repeated again.

Comment: I get it. I guess to answer your original question, it's 100% best practice to take a value from one Observable and save it to another one. To get around the component being destroyed, though, the best practice is to put this in a service, that way it stays intact.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Please edit your answer with this information so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

i think the answer you found is the best way to reach what you want to do. you can make a shared state with the time of interval and when you create the dynamic component you check the interval and based on it make the http call I think in all ways you will need an outer state that you can listen to because you will destroy the interval every time you create the component.